# Swift Custom Navigation Controller

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, xcode6

i can't find how to create a custom navigation controller with a left button and also the back button without label..
An Example : http://www.imore.com/sites/imore.com/files/styles/xlarge/public/field/image/2014/11/amazon_app_iphone_6_best_apps_screens.jpg?itok=rcopxSde

As you see in the third screen, there is the back button and also the three lines button, i would like to create something like this.

Thank you really much :)

Comment: Did you try reading the docs? This is elementary stuff. Look at how a view controller's `navigationItem` works.

Comment: @matt Looks like he wants to add two buttons on the left side, which is not that trivial.

Comment: @DaniilKorotin It's a straightforward built-in behavior, well documented under UINavigationItem. If he has trouble with that part, he should show his code and ask about it specifically. This question at it stands is too broad to be useful.

Comment: @matt it's the `backBarButtonItem` ?

Comment: It's the `leftBarButtonItem`.

Comment: i want to edit the back bar button so i don't see the label in it and i would like to add a second button on the left, i don't want to add only 1 button